# Is Azure Blob storage the right place to store many (small) communication logs?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

I am working with a program which connects to multiple APIs, the logs for each operation (HTML/XML/Json) need to be stored for possible later review. Is it feasible to store each request/reply in an Azure blob? There can be hundreds of requests per second (all of which need storing) which vary in size and have an average size of 100kB.

Because the logs need to be searchable (by metadata) my plan is to store it in Azure Blob and put metadata (with blob locations, custom application-related request and content identifiers, etc) in an easily-searchable database.

Comment: How large will your logs per operation be?

Comment: @RobReagan About 100kB per communication log.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can store logs in the Azure table storage or Blob storage but Microsoft itself recommends using Blob storage. Azure Storage Analytics stores log data in Blob storage.

This '[Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#log-data-anti-pattern)' points out several draw backs of using table storage for logs and also provides details on how to use the blob storage to store logs. Read the 'Log data anti-pattern' section in particular for this use case.

Comment: Is it the cost effective way to store the logs?